Is the set of functions $\left\{1, x, e^{n x}: n \in \mathbb{Z}^*\right\}$ linearly independent?
This functions are part of Hilbert space $\mathfrak{L}^2\left(\mathbb{R}, e^{-x^2 / 2}\right)$ with the inner product: $$
\langle f \mid g\rangle=\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) e^{-x^2 / 2} \mathrm{~d} x \quad \text { where } \quad\|f\|^2=\langle f, f\rangle
$$
I should show that the only solution for $$\alpha_0+\alpha_1 x+\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^*} \beta_n e^{n x}=0$$ where $\left\{\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_n :n\in\mathbb{Z}^*\right\}\in\mathbb{C}$ is $\alpha_0=\alpha_1=\beta_n=0$. I have arrived to
$$\begin{aligned}
-\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^*} \beta_n&=\alpha_0\\
-\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^*} n \beta_n&=\alpha_1\\
 \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^*} n^k\beta_n&=0\quad\forall k\geq 2.
\end{aligned}$$ How can I arrive to the conclusion that all the $\beta_n$ are zero?

Yes. You can do it by taking derivatives, or comparing their growth rates.

Do you intend to write infinite sums? What do those mean?

@TedShifrin I guess the sum is finite. Otherwise you have to assume some growth condition on $\beta_n$ so that the infinite sum belongs to $L^2(e^{-x^2}).$

Those are actually infinite sums, maybe with an infinite sum is possible to have $\beta_n$ different from zero as a solution of the equation? PS: I am not focused on linear independence, I am more interested in solving an equation with infinite sums.
